# Unable to create a java project in android studio

Tags: java, android

I can't choose java in the android studio, why is that?

[no option for choosing java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t69Qz.png)

Im new to android studio and tried to configure by following a tutorial video, but didn't work.

[JAVA version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmw5o.png)

[environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylO9j.png)

is there something I didn't do or something didn't configured correctly?

I would be appreciated if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the top of the window in your screenshot. You chose Empty Activity. Choose Empty Views Activity in the previous dialog instead and you'll be able to select Java as the language.

Comment: one more question, what's the difference between Language and Build Configuration Language?

Comment: Build configuration language is the one used to configure the gradle build scripts. It can be either Groovy or Kotlin.